# How do I animate a glowing effect on text?

Tags: css, css-animations

I haven't really been able to find any good simple tutorials an animating a glow effect. How do I animate glowing on text?

Comment: We need more than "animating a glow effect". What do you want this animation to look like? Changing color? Changing glow radius?

Comment: anything, once I'm started, I can tweak it from there. Cause it's just css properties.

Comment: well, i do suppose I should have specified that I DO mean CSS3 properties, more specifically text/box-shadow. I just assumed when people think of glow, they think of something having an aura... like radiating part of it's energy.  oops.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you want to just use CSS3, you don't even have to use any jQuery/JavaScript. Just do this in your CSS:

```
.confirm_selection {
    -webkit-transition: text-shadow 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: text-shadow 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: text-shadow 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: text-shadow 0.2s linear;
    transition: text-shadow 0.2s linear;
}
.confirm_selection:hover {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px red; /* replace with whatever color you want */
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zenjJ/

If you want the element to run on its own (without hovering), do this:

CSS:

```
.confirm_selection {
    -webkit-transition: text-shadow 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: text-shadow 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: text-shadow 1s linear;
    -o-transition: text-shadow 1s linear;
    transition: text-shadow 1s linear;
}
.confirm_selection:hover,
.confirm_selection.glow {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var glow = $('.confirm_selection');
setInterval(function(){
    glow.toggleClass('glow');
}, 1000);
```

You can play around with the timing in the CSS/JavaScript to get the exact effect you're looking for.

And finally, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dH6LS/

---

**Update Oct. 2013:** being that all major browsers now support CSS animations, all you need is this:

```css
.confirm_selection {
    animation: glow .5s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes glow {
    to {
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
    }
}

.confirm_selection {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<span class="confirm_selection">
[ Confirm Selection ]
</span>
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dH6LS/689/

Don't forget to include all the different vendor prefixes in production.

Comment: despite the October '13 Update probably being the preferred method for modern browsers, cross-browser methods rule. setInterval loops for the win!

Comment: Great update. Works great for my 'pulse' text effect. I used ease-in-out and a slight delay, but based off of this.

Comment: And even if you did use `transition`, you don't have to vendor-prefix it: http://shouldiprefix.com/#transitions

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate) to cycle to a chosen colour to create a "highlight" effect which is presumably what "glowing" means.

```
$(".confirm_selection").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        color: "red"
    }, 2000);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        color: "black"
    }, 2000);
});
```

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/G3J6V/1/)

*NOTE: Colour animation requires the use of either the colour animation plugin, or jQuery UI (which I assume you are already using as it has been included in your fiddle).*

Comment: Don't forget that jQuery does not natively support color animation. You'll have to either use jQuery UI, or the color animation plugin.

Comment: You can actually animate using CSS3 transitions.

Comment: what about the css3 properties? can I animate text-shadow?

Comment: Definition of glowing: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/glowing emitting light. I thought this was well known. =D

Comment: @TheLindyHop - My understanding of "a glowing element" happens to be one which brightens, then dims. :D

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with pure CSS3 transitions:

```
div.transition{
    text-decoration: none;  
    color: blue;  
    text-shadow: none;  
    -webkit-transition: 500ms linear 0s;  
    -moz-transition: 500ms linear 0s;  
    -o-transition: 500ms linear 0s;  
    transition: 500ms linear 0s;  
    outline: 0 none; 
    background-color:#000; 
    font-size:2em;
    width:300px;     
    height:100px; 
    padding:1em;
}

div.transition:hover {
    color: #fff;  
    text-shadow: -1px 1px 8px #ffc, 1px -1px 8px #fff; 
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/z5jCB/1/

*Note: Glowing text works best on a dark background.*

Inspiration (and much of the code) from here: http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-glowing-link-effect/

Comment: that is sexy. Is there a way to make it pulse? like... do the animation without the :hover?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var glow = $('h1');
    setInterval(function()
    {
        glow.toggleClass('glow');
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    h1 {
        -webkit-transition: text-shadow 1s linear;
        -moz-transition: text-shadow 1s linear;
        -ms-transition: text-shadow 1s linear;
        -o-transition: text-shadow 1s linear;
        transition: text-shadow 1s linear;
        width: 725px;
    }
    h1:hover,
    h1.glow
    {
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px Green;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>This text has Glow Animation Effect</h1>
    <div class="buttons">
        <input type="text" name="txt"> <input type="button" class="btnAdd" value="Add"><br>
    </div>
    <h3>J Query</h3>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an animated pure CSS example:

```
@keyframes shadow {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 10px gray;
  }
  25% {
    text-shadow: -5px 5px 10px gray;
  }
  50% {
    text-shadow: -5px -5px 10px gray;
  }
  75% {
    text-shadow: 5px -5px 10px gray;
  }
}

h1 {
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 10px gray;
  animation: shadow 2s infinite ease;
}
```

[image]
https://codepen.io/juanbrujo/pen/abyoXNY

Comment: Not my cup of tea but worth a vote for including a `.gif` which saves people time from putting the code in themselves to see the effect.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [on-line](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_glowing_text.asp) and it only took a couple of minutes to setup:

```css
// Neon glowing Text: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_glowing_text.asp
.glow {
  // font-size: 80px; // Way TOO BIG
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation: glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: glow 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes glow {
  from {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #e60073, 0 0 40px #e60073, 0 0 50px #e60073, 0 0 60px #e60073, 0 0 70px #e60073;
  }
  to {
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #ff4da6, 0 0 40px #ff4da6, 0 0 50px #ff4da6, 0 0 60px #ff4da6, 0 0 70px #ff4da6, 0 0 80px #ff4da6;
  }
}
```

I don't like the colors and will change them to a fire color (if I can figure out the codes):

[image: Pippim Neon Glowing Title.gif]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an animation effect that I have found useful in the past by adding a new step function to the **jQuery fx** object.

```
$.fx.step.myBlurRedEffect = function (fx) {
    $(fx.elem).css({
        textShadow: '0 0 ' + Math.floor(fx.now) + 'px #FF0000'
    });
}
```

Which is called in the usual way (say blur 6px in half a second):

```
$('#myID').animate({
    myBlurRedEffect: 6
},{
    duration: 500
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/whLMZ/1/

This should get you started, and you should find many fun ways to extend upon this, add other CSS parameters etc... :)

Comment: @TheLindyHop I added a working version. You set the CSS attribute to an invalid value "text-shadow:4 4 [x]px #FFFFFF" (4 what?).

Comment: @TheLindyHop Just putting it out there again [http://jsfiddle.net/whLMZ/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/whLMZ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

No one mention css3 keyframes which can animate the glow effect getting rid of javascript(this coming from a javascript dev).

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        :root { --color: blue; }
        span.vjs { --color: #F3E5AB; }
        span.cv { --color: skyblue; }
        body {background:gray;}
        .vjs, .cv, h1 {
          text-align: center;
          font-size: 30pt;
          font-weight: 100;
          font-family: cursive2;
        }
        .vjs {
          text-shadow: 0 0 2px #333333, 0 0 4px #333333;
          color: var(--color);
        }
        .cv {
          text-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff, 0 0 4px #fff;
          color: #2965f1;
        }
        h1 {
          text-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff, 0 0 4px #fff;
          color:black;
        }
        .cv:hover, .vjs:hover, h1:hover {
            animation: glow 1s linear infinite;
            color: var(--color);
        }
        @keyframes glow {
            0% {text-shadow: 0 0 0px var(--color);}
            50% {text-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--color);}
            100% {text-shadow: 0 0 0px var(--color);}
        }
    </style>
    <script src="vanilla-js.com/lib/vanilla.4.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h1>This text has Real Glow Animation Effect with 
<span class="vjs">Vanilla JS</span>And <span class="cv">CSS Variables</span>. Hover over all the texts!</h1>
    </body>

    </html>
```

A [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lv2lrn4lf/8ft7L02z/)