# jQuery glowing animations : how to improve?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

I've been making things glow with CSS and jQuery (simple CSS style change, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061420/how-do-i-animate-a-glowing-effect-on-text)), and now I wonder how to make these animations even better.

For the moment, I'm just making a transition between no box shadow and a box shadow, and that looks good. But I'm trying to find how to make it look even better, like if it was some sort of fog : basically, instead of having a fixed length of the box shadow, having it being longer here and shorter there (irregular shadow, so to speak).

Now I don't expect that to be possible with CSS3's box-shadow (but perhaps I'm wrong), so I wondered how to produce the effect I'm searching with jQuery. Is there a way to generate some layers with jQuery? Or perhaps creating a ghost text and using its text shadow?

I'm opened to various solutions here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where? For the moment I'm using a box shadow (my div glows), but I'm wondering how to make the shadow irregular.

Comment: I re-read a couple of times your question, and still I'm confused about: *'I'm just making a transition between no box shadow and a box shadow'* and *'Or perhaps creating a ghost text and using its text shadow?'* - you mean... to create a ghost text and use it's shadows as a 'irregular' box shadow?

Comment: For the moment, I'm just making a boxshadow appear and fade. As a box shadow in itself is necessarily regular, I'm wondering if using a fake text shadow couldn't appear like an irregular box shadow around my div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it might be helpful to see what you have to compare if our suggestions are "better".

I will tell you that contrast is really your friend when it comes to glowing though.  I wrote some quick examples here to show a few different ideas.  I used text-shadow here for the glow and you can stack them up to change the glow (for example, see 3rd option). If you want it to "animate" you can put it on a setinterval to toggle between classes (see first option).

I'm using jquery and jquery UI for the class toggle, but there are other alternatives as well.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mikecruz/zjbXa

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually using setinterval but I'm interested in "randomizing" the glowing effect... A rotating text-shadow might do the trick ^^

Comment: IF you want to "randomize" it, I would suggest programmatically by either selecting different classes or changing the x-val, y-val, length, and color attributes of the text-shadow css.

Comment: No problem.  Added 1 to quickly some motion, sure you could play with the numbers and such to make it better: http://jsfiddle.net/mikecruz/DBtnJ/

Answer (score 1):

see this http://www.css3.info/preview/text-shadow/

it might be helpul

example for this http://jsfiddle.net/zenjJ/102/

use

```
text-shadow: 0 0 4px white, 0 -5px 4px #FFFF33, 2px -10px 6px #FFDD33, -2px -15px 11px #FF8800, 2px -25px 18px #FF2200;
```

to achieve irregular shadow effect

Comment: Thank you! If I can't find anything else, I'll try to make a fake changing text behind my div, so that the text shadow appears like a moving box shadow. I'm still searching for something simpler though ^^